# Imagemagick inline border without resizing the original image

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I tried to add a border to an image of dimension 200x200 px using the below code.

```
convert -border 2x2 -bordercolor "#cccccc" old.png new.png
```

The above code ads a 2 px border **around** the old.png. Therefore, the image expands to 204x204 px.

However, I want to add an **inline** border. I have no issues with border **overlaying** edge portions of the old image. Thus, the new image should be able to retain the dimensions 200x200 px. Please advise how exactly to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to shave two pixels all around and then add a two pixel border. You should try this with Imagemagick 6. If using Imagemagick 7, replace convert with magick.

```
convert old.png -shave 2x2 -bordercolor "#cccccc" -border 2 new.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Python, I wanted to add padding. not sure about cli version. To do this in Python:

- Add border

> img.border(color=background, width=50, height=50)

- Resize the image to the original width and height

> img.resize(width=width, height=height)

Sample Code:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
background = Color("transparent")
with Image(width=width, height=height, background=background) as img:
    // whatever you want to do
    img.border(color=background, width=50, height=50)
    img.resize(width=width, height=height)
    img.save(filename=filename)
```